# SharePoint 2010 Webservice GetListeItems response for a list item returns multiple authors

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, metadata

I am creating a file in a document library with SharePoint Webservices all well and good.

Now I needed to override the created by/modified by and dates as well, so I created a SOAP service on the SharePoint server that uses listItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion() that can set those values. Working and looks good when I click "View Properties" in SharePoint.

Now to my problem/question, when I call GetListItems.asmx to view the document again (SOAP services), the author I created it with at first is still listed there (I do also see the one I did an overwrite with).

So why am I seeing this... it's as if I did an overwrite, but still keep the original author.

To keep it short, why am i seeing both of these:

vti_author:SR|TEST\tm (user used to create document with)
and 
display_urn\:schemas-microsoft-com\:office\:office#Author:SW|TEST\Administrator (user set as new creator on overwrite)

What is the meaning of SR versus SW?

I have pasted the full item response for "GetListItems" command

```
<z:row ows_ID="63" 
       ows_Title="Even NS 1.0" 
       ows_MetaInfo="63;#display_urn\:schemas-microsoft-com\:office\:office#Editor:SW|TEST\\Administrator
           vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.4762
           vti_folderitemcount:IR|0
           Order:DW|6300.00000000000Site / LocationTaxHTField0:SW|Singapore|dc0e351b-e873-453c-8d23-6b0e21b8360a
           Subject Matter Expert:IW|3
           vti_author:SR|TEST\\tm
           vti_modifiedby:SR|TEST\\tm
           _CopySource:SW|c:\\SharePoint Source\\Pdfs\\wicketBasic.pdf
           vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0
           TopicsTaxHTField0:SW|Molds|cddd6251-227d-4bb0-86aa-ff5ed715602f;Etiolog|63537636-fbdd-4071-8e1d-0c5cfcec84e3;Allergies|8ca11784-e48a-4d70-a22d-43a06f33f0a2
           Document Status:SW|Review
           display_urn\:schemas-microsoft-com\:office\:office#Author:SW|TEST\\Administrator
           ContentTypeId:SW|0x0101000FF13CC8F9D9B5408C6B72B560B15D6600C85CC76A22DB0D4298AC2D15EBF60842
           vti_title:SW|Even NS 1.0
           Topics:SW|9;#Molds|cddd6251-227d-4bb0-86aa-ff5ed715602f;#10;#Etiolog|63537636-fbdd-4071-8e1d-0c5cfcec84e3;#11;#Allergies|8ca11784-e48a-4d70-a22d-43a06f33f0a2 
           Site / Location:SW|8;#Singapore|dc0e351b-e873-453c-8d23-6b0e21b8360a
           TaxCatchAll:SW|10;#Etiolog|63537636-fbdd-4071-8e1d-0c5cfcec84e3;#9;#Molds|cddd6251-227d-4bb0-86aa-ff5ed715602f;#8;#Singapore|dc0e351b-e873-453c-8d23-6b0e21b8360a;#11;#Allergies|8ca11784-e48a-4d70-a22d-43a06f33f0a2
           display_urn\:schemas-microsoft-com\:office\:office#Subject_x0020_Matter_x0020_Expert:SW|TEST\\Administrator"
      ows__ModerationStatus="0" 
      ows__Level="1" 
      ows_Last_x0020_Modified="63;#2011-09-27 00:57:18" 
      ows_UniqueId="63;#{369FADAB-58E1-4C00-B279-6966D3FDB725}" 
      ows_owshiddenversion="5" 
      ows_FSObjType="63;#0" 
      ows_Created_x0020_Date="63;#2011-09-27 00:57:18" 
      ows_ProgId="63;#" 
      ows_FileLeafRef="63;#wicketBasic.pdf"
      ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff"
      ows_Modified="2011-09-27 00:57:18" 
      ows_FileRef="63;#Sync Source/wicketBasic.pdf"
      ows_DocIcon="pdf"
      ows_Editor="3;#TEST\Administrator"></z:row>
```

Comment: I am looking it more now (note I only have one version of the document) and I see that if I do a GetVersions on the document I see the original creator (so looks like the webservices are querying a different dataset on list operations) but then if I use GetVersionCollection for field Author, the proper value is there. It doesn't answer my own question directly, but it may have something to do with that.